# How to generate count query for a group by select query in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I have a group by query which produces 6303 rows.

```
SELECT item_id, discount_id 
FROM xyz
GROUP BY item_id, discount_id
```

Then DISTINCT also produces 6303 rows (including null values of discount_id).

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id, discount_id 
FROM xyz
```

But, this gives 6257 count as it eliminates null values of discount_id.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT item_id, discount_id)
FROM xyz
```

The last one again produces count 6303 but this is a subquery which is increasing the query time from 0.000 to 0.453. Please suggest.

```
SELECT COUNT(0) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT item_id, discount_id 
    FROM xyz) AS tbl
```

Comment: How large are your real tables?  What exactly you want to see as the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have one value, that is guaranteed to be never used as a `discount_id` e.g. 0, you can use

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT item_id, IFNULL(discount_id,0))
FROM xyz
```

Comment: Found the answer on another site. Thanks though. Superb.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item_id, discount_id, count(*)
FROM xyz
GROUP BY item_id, discount_id
```

To produce the # of rows for each unique combination of item_id and discount_id assuming that is what you want.